# Onclick select File is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to select file when user click on button but that is not working in chrome only

Here See this how i did that

```
$("#upllnk").click(function() {
    $("#ufile").click();
});
```

Here is my html Code

```
<a href="#" class="wb" id="upllnk">Select File To Upload</a>
<div style='display:none'><input type='file' name='ufile' id='ufile'/></div>
```

Reason for Putting input:file in div is to hide that element.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBtwL/1/

Comment: Works fine in my version of chrome.

Comment: It doesn't work in earlier versions of chrome

Comment: @Esailija: Which versions?  That doesn't help us at all.

Comment: I don't remember when it was changed, though I doubt the OP has that early version of chrome anyway. I just remember it didn't work in 2010. It doesn't work in safari 5.1 either.

Comment: @Esailija, was it a security thing? Maybe to prevent the uploading dialogue from opening without user's click?

Comment: @Adnan there is a click involved, it's inside a click handler. I am saying regardless of that, it didn't work in chrome. My chrome-only app I made in 2010 is still using the opacity 0 hack because of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija)'s helpful comment, I downloaded a portable version of Google Chrome (8.0.552.215) and indeed it didn't work.

As Esailija suggested you can use the `opacity` workaround

```
<div style='opacity:0;'><input type='file' name='ufile' id='ufile'/></div>
            ^^^^^^^^^ setting the opacity to 0 "hides" the input element
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCaHJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Triggering a click via JavaScript on a file input triggers security errors (usually after trying to submit the form) and in general doesn't work like you'd expect. This is very prevalent in IE and early versions of Chrome and Firefox.

I've gotten around this problem in the past by wrapping the input in a label. That way, when the label is clicked, it will trigger the input.

`.Foo input { visibility: hidden; }`

`<label class="Foo">Select File to Upload<input type="file" /></label>`